# Nature of a superposition of states: is it true or only theoretical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, superposition

For quantum mechanics, a certain property of a subatomic particle, e.g. the spin of an electron, which can be either up or down, is a "superposition of states," and one of the two conditions, e.g. the fact that it has spin up or down, doesn't manifest itself until the situation is experimentally observed. In fact, from what I understand, it **does not exist** until you observe it.
So what I would like to understand is a very precise thing: does the electron have a real spin or does it only have it when it is observed?

Does the spin of an electron have an a priori value (unknown to me until I observe it), or does it have a superposed state?
As Einstein said to someone, "Do you really believe that the Moon only exists when you look at it?"
I understand that the observation itself changes the state of the electron, but could this mean that its spin goes from up to down as a result of the observation, or vice versa, or does it mean that it just doesn't have a definite spin?
The fact is controversial to me, but if reality were only true when observed there would be paradoxical, or even physically impossible, consequences.

Comment: We can't tell you what is "true" in your terms. We can only tell you what experiments show. The Universe has no obligation to conform to the way you wish to model it. Our models must adapt to what we actually see.

Comment: First of all, how can you really know that any physical phenomenon exists before you observe it? Second, quantum mechanics theory basically says that information and physics are tightly related. In particular, when information about a physical thing is moved (e.g. from an atom into a photon that scatters from the atom), then the physical state of the thing must change in a well-defined way. You can actually calculate that the physical process you call "observing" pushes the spin toward either "up" or "down", regardless of the spin's initial state.

Comment: However, there is a very strange thing here, which is that whether the spin goes to up or down is *random*. Intrinsically random. That part is really weird and we don't have an explanation for "why" that randomness exists.

Comment: Humans are limited to model dependent realism, beyond that, we can know nothing else; scientifically at least.  Which has the unfortunate consequence of implying that what we call "real" is possibly non-unique. Science is an attempt to do one's best and find the simplest model that best explains all the empirical facts as we know them.

Comment: See Griffiths, David J. *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*. "Chapter 12 Afterword", 2nd ed. There is a good discussion concerning the interpretation of quantum mechanics;, especially the realist, orthodox and agnostic responses.

Comment: Have you heard of Schrödinger’s cat?

Answer (score 4):

The premise of your question is not correct: we *can* experimentally observe superpositions, just not directly. There are many examples of this, but maybe the most famous one is [the double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment). I encourage you to take a look for yourself, but the key point is that **the existence of superpositions manifests itself through the emergence of interference patterns in our experiments**. This is why we conjured up the concept of superposition in the first place!

Superpositions are essentially a manifestation of the wave-like bahaviour of quantum particles (again, look at the damn experiment, it's crazy cool!).

*Warning, this next part is a little bit more tecnical:*

If you really dislike the concept of superposition you could try to just stop imagining particles as discrete objects and start treating them strictly as waves<sup>1</sup>, but this is hardly productive, it's better to stick to what the experiments tells us: sometimes particles behave like classical dot particles, sometimes they behave like classical waves, and that makes them neither of those two. Quantum particles are, well, quantum particles! Their physical state is well represented by vectors in Hilbert space, so linear objects that support being linearly combined in the basis of eigenstates of observables (remember that QM dynamics is linear), *id est* support superpositions.

---

**[1]:** But there is no escape from wave-particle duality, so prepare to accept that a [Dirac's delta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) is a wave!

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: How does the pattern observed in a two-slit experiment proves that the electron's properties are not definite?

Comment: @Andrei The properties are definite, and guess what, also the state is definite, always! (Well for *pure states* that is, but let's not get into that rabbit hole..) The thing that the pattern proves is that the definite electron state can be a superposition of observable's eigenstates.

Comment: @Noumeno, I reformulate. How does the pattern observed in a two-slit proves that the electron does not always behave as a particle (like in always having a well-defined - even if unknown position, passes through only one slit, etc)?

Comment: @Andrei Something is telling me that you didn't take a proper look at the experiment.. If the electrons was behaving classically then you would observe a distribution with only two bands, no interference pattern, like if you were shooting with a machine gun at the two gaps. I suggest you take a proper look at the experiment, you will find good descriptions for it on a lot of reputable resources

Answer (score 1):

There is a strong argument, based on the EPR-Bohm setup (a pair of spin-entangled particles) that proves that, as long as physics is local (no physical effect can propagate faster than the speed of light) the properties must exist before measurement. Here is the argument:

A pair of spin-entangled particles will always be perfectly anti-correlated when measured along the same direction. If one particle is found UP at location A the other is found DOWN at location B with probability 1. The measurements could be space-like, so there is no time for a signal at the speed of light to travel between A and B. Let's analyze the available options:

1. Both measurement results are randomly generated at the time of measurement (there is nothing that uniquely determines the outcomes)
   In this case, the probability for anti-correlation is 0.5 (independent coin-flips). This is different from the observed one (1), therefore this option is falsified by experiment.
2. One outcome, say at A, is random and the other one is determined by it.
   Such a scenario can give you the probability 1 for anti correlation, but since the measurements can be space-like it requires a faster than light signal to travel from A to B (non-locality). It's inconsistent with relativity which is fundamental for all modern physical theories (Standard model and general Relativity), so it's not very likely.
3. both outcomes are determined, the measurements just reveal the pre-existent properties of the particles.
   This scenario is consistent with all physical laws including relativity, therefore it is the most likely.

So, the evidence strongly favors the measered properties are real even before measurement. The superposition is just a mathematical representation of our lack of information regarding the true state of the system.

Comment: "If one particle is found UP at location A the other is found DOWN at location B with probability 1" --- There a four different Bell states, all of which are maximally entangled. Two of those have the same spin orientation in each term, which would contradict your statement.

Comment: A pair of entangled spin 1/2 particles - prepared, say, from positronium - will always show perfect anticorrelations when measured in the same direction.

Comment: Now I'm really confused... What is the most adherent explanation?

Comment: @Bml, you need to look at the arguments. The argument I presented is simple, logically sound and based on a premise (locality) which sits at the foundation of modern physics (GR and QFT). There is no good argument proving the reality of superpositions. Yes, in a two-slit experiment you get a pattern that resembles wave interference. This does not prove that the electron passes through both slits. It could pass through one but be influenced by the second via electromagnetic forces.

Comment: This old argument (originally from EPR, 1935) in favor of "local realism" (your option 3) is completely wrong. It is ruled out by Bell's Theorem (1964) as well as hundreds of experiments disproving local realism.

Comment: @bml This answer should be ignored. It was discredited by Bell over 50 years ago. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem Quantum mechanics follows special relativity in the limited sense that signal cannot be transmitted faster than light.  But there are literally hundreds of experiments that demonstrate that quantum theory is nonlocal (FTL) and/or does not respect normal cause and effect. A common example of that is quantum teleportation, which is not limited by the speed of light. Note that such teleportation does NOT teleport an object, it teleports a quantum state.

Comment: @DrChinese, you fail repeatedly to address the simple argument above. Bell didn't discredit anything. It's clear that you didn't even bother to read Bell's paper.

Comment: @DrChinese, even your Wikipedia link invalidates your assertion. Superdeterminism allows local-hidden variable models.

Comment: @DrChinese, there is no relativistic description of the measurement in QM. So, QM, as it stands, is not a relativistic theory.

Comment: You obviously have never understood the math of Bell. Otherwise you would know why your explanation is ruled out. Here is my web page that explains the math in easy to understand terms: https://drchinese.com/David/Bell_Theorem_Easy_Math.htm

Comment: There is no theory called "superdeterminism". If there were, it would give physicists something to laugh at while tearing it apart. Superdeterminism cannot be critically assessed because there is nothing to assess. You may as well explain quantum phenomena by saying God does it.

Comment: @DrChinese, of course there is no theory called "superdeterminism" just like there is no theory called "determinism" or "locality". Superdeterminism is a feature some theories may or may not have. If you want to "critically assess" superdeterminismic models I invite you to look at 't Hooft's cellular automaton interpretation (Explicit construction of Local Hidden Variables for any quantum theory up to any desired accuracy - https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.04335), Wetterich’s model (Probabilistic cellular automata for interacting fermionic quantum field theories - https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.06366)

Comment: @DrChinese, Stochastic electrodinamics (Stochastic Electrodynamics: The Closest Classical Approximation to Quantum Theory - https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00996) or Tim Palmer's Invariant Set model (Superdeterminism Without Conspiracy - https://arxiv.org/pdf/2308.11262.pdf). Please let me know when you finish your assessment of those!

Comment: I was already familiar with Palmer's work, both alone and with Hossenfelder. I would not call his/their work an interpretation. And no, denying statistical independence does not salvage Superdeterminism. A comment is not a place to debate this, but the existence of the GHZ theorem alone is enough to torpedo that (since there are no statistics involved).

Comment: @DrChinese, "denying statistical independence does not salvage Superdeterminism". What? Denying statistical independence is the definition of superdeterminism. You clearly have no clue what you are speaking about.

Comment: Palmer denies SI. But that *alone* does not mean anything, and certainly does not amount to justification of any form of superdeterminism. There are many things required to make sense of the preposterous hypothesis of SD. Again, this is no place to debate this subject.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Experiment: Using a Mach Zehnder Interferometer to observe Quantum Interference using a Single Photon Beam]

Reference: [Experiment: Using a Mach Zehnder Interferometer to observe Quantum Interference using a Single Photon Beam](https://sites.google.com/a/umn.edu/mxp/advanced-labs/single-photon-quantum-interference-lab/single-photon-interferometer)

A Mach Zehnder interferometer (single photon at a time version) works as it does (all photons going to the same single output port of a beam splitter) precisely because the photons are in a **superposition of states**. See the diagram, that output port is labeled D.  In this version, the BBo crystal creates 2 photons at a time, one detected at A and the other at D.  None exist the output port marked with red dashes going to the black dash.

In your parlance: the "up" outcome (going one path, by M1) and the "down" outcome (going the other path, by M2) interfere constructively/destructively where they recombine. You might reasonably conclude that both exist, but each only 50% exist. (No one knows exactly, there are a number of ways to think of it.) If that were not the case, the photons would leave the two output ports of the beam splitter going equally (and randomly) out the two ports (rather than only to the D one).

In actual experiments, you cannot say which path the photon took. So there is no "observation" - only a "paradoxical" result. That being, the photon takes both paths in some sense - and interferes with only itself.

But this phenomenon only occurs with photons in a superposition.  So I would call it both experimentally real *and* theoretically predicted.  As others have pointed out, there is no one "true" description that all would agree on.

Comment: I don't see what is the argument here. Why is this experiment in contradiction with the assumption that the particle has definite properties before being measured?

Comment: @Andrei If it has properties that sent it strictly to a single path (and not a superposition), there would be no single particle interference.  50% of the outcomes would be photon detection coincidences between A & D, and the other 50% would be A only. But in an actual experiment, essentially all outcomes are coincidences between A & D. That is the demonstration of the superposition effect. There are many experiments which demonstrate this in one way or another.

Comment: The result can be explained in terms of correlations between the properties of the photons generated at the source and the rest of the setup. Such correlations are expected in a correct treatment of the experiment which takes into account the electromagnetic interactions between all parts of the setup.